# customised random string generator in ruby

Tags: ruby, random

Below is my code to generate a random string by taking the number of length from the user . I want to enhance this by asking the user to enter number of numbers and special characters to be included and generate a string to match those requirements.

For example:

```
length: 7
number of numbers: 2
number of special chars: 1
```

Then my output should be something like:

```
ab2hg3!
```

Below is my code:

```
puts "enter the minimum length of the password"
lengths = gets.to_i
puts "enter the number of numbers to be included"
num = gets.to_i

def gen_pass(lengths)
    chars = ('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a + (0..10).to_a
    Array.new(lengths) {chars.sample}.join
end

puts gen_pass(lengths)
puts gen_pass(lengths)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def gen_pass(lengths, number_of_numbers, number_of_special_chars)
    chars = ('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a + (0..10).to_a
    digits = (0..9).to_a
    special_chars = "?<>',?[]}{=-)(*&^%$#`~{}".split('')
    remaining_letters_count = lengths - number_of_numbers - number_of_special_chars

    n = digits.sample(number_of_numbers)
    s = special_chars.sample(number_of_special_chars)
    c = chars.sample(remaining_letters_count)

    str = n << s << c
    str.flatten.shuffle.join
end

puts gen_pass(lengths, number_of_numbers, number_of_special_chars)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked :) I got an idea of the methods to be used . Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is an exercise you should do it yourself. If it's not, you are certainly doing it wrong.
Anyway, here is my try :

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def secret(l,n,s)
    random_string = 
      [*('A'..'Z'),*('a'..'z')].sample(l-n-s) +
      [*('0'..'9')].sample(n)                 +
      [*('!'..'/')].sample(s)
    random_string.shuffle.join
end

p secret(5,2,1)
=> ".4F0r"
```